# Conjugacy class size of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups

My algebra text writes for the number of cyclic structures (-,-)(-,-) in $S_4$

$\frac{{4\choose 2}\cdot {2 \choose 2}} {2}$

which should be {(1 2)(3 4), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4) (2 3)}.

The binomial coefficient part "$C_{4,2} \cdot C_{2,2}$" should mean select 2 objects out 4 for the first cycle and 2 out the remaining 2 for the second cycle. I don't understand what dividing by 2 accomplishes, the author does not provide any information about it. I'd like to understand it from a combinatorics point of view, and be able to generalize to $S_n$.

So far I've understood that the length of a *r*-cycle is n!/r(n − r)!. But I'm unsure how to pass from *r*-cycles to product of *r*-cycles.

Comment: Basically it captures the idea that it is immaterial whether you first picked $(12)$ and then $(34)$ or whether you first picked $(34)$ and then $(12)$. In other words, you want to avoid overcounting.

Comment: If we were calculating the number of cyclic structures (-,-)(-,-)(-,-) in S_6, we would divide by 3!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But combinations do not imply any ordering property by definition. So C(4,2) does not enumerate the permutations of (1 2) or of (34).

Comment: You misunderstood. There are two stages call: them $C(4,2)$ and $C(2,2)$. The two in the denominator is there because otherwise getting $(12)$ from the $C(4,2)$ stage and $(34)$ from the $C(2,2)$ stage is counted separately from getting $(34)$ in the $C(4,2)$ stage and $(12)$ in the $C(2,2)$ stage even though $(12)(34)$ and $(34)(12)$ are the same permutation. So the two in the denominator cancels this overcounting.

Comment: If you try to count permutations of type $(2,2,2)$ in $S_6$ you select the pairs forming the 2-cycles in three stages. Because you don't care about the ordering of the stages, the answer is
$$\frac{\binom 62 \binom 42 \binom 22}{3!}=15.$$

Comment: it's an improvement to understand that's not a 2 but a 2!. I was trying to calculate |(-,-,-)(-,-)| in $S_5$. By applying the same reasoning I got

$\frac{\binom 53 \binom 22}{2!} =5.$
but there must be something wrong

Comment: That does not apply to permutations of cycle type $(3,2)$. The two disjoint cycles are not interchangable because their lengths are not equal. That extra factor in the numerator is needed only when there are cycles of the same length. Also, after you selected the numbers participating in the 3-cycle you can still form $(3-1)!=$ distinct 3-cycles from them (more generally you can build $(k-1)!$ distinct $k$-cycles involving any selection of $k$ digits. So the number of permutations of type $(3,2)$ in $S_5$ is equal to
$$\binom 53 \cdot (3-1)!\binom 22=20.$$

Comment: On the other hand, the number of permutations of type $(2,2)$ in $S_5$ is
$$\frac{\binom 52 \binom 32}{2!}$$
and the number of permutations of type $(3,3)$ in $S_6$ is
$$\frac{\binom 63\cdot (3-1)!\binom 33\cdot(3-1)!}{2!}.$$